# Setting CollectionView cell height to dynamic based on content

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have an application where I am using collectionview to display content which includes imageview, about 4 uilabels and a stackview which are all constrained to each other. This cell is scrollable vertically and not horizontally as I have to make provison for larger screen size like the iPad. The problem I have now is my CollectionViewFlowLayout height is static, How can I make it dynamic so that it resizes base on the height of the retuned content. the text of the label could vary so how do I handle this

below is how I have made my cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: 400)
    }
```

further code would be added on request and any help is appritiated

Comment: but I need to also make plans for bigger screen so as to display content well, what do you suggest @Sh_Khan